# Difference between 07h and 08h services of INT 21h in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

Both the services (07h and 08h) of INT 21h have the same purpose (console input without echo) as mentioned in [DOS INT 21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html). But it also mentions a small difference which is **07h does not check ^C/^Break while as 08h does**.

Looking it up on the Internet I found that [^C/^Break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key) in modern keyboards is enforced with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key combinations. So I did that on both of the services and guess what both of them terminate. But the documentation says 07h shouldn't. So what is the difference between the two then?

**My Code:**

```
   .model small
   .data
   .code
   .startup

        mov ah, 08h ; or mov ah, 07h
        int 21h

        mov ah, 04ch
        int 21h

   end
```

Comment: Is there any difference in the exit code between these two routines in the cases they were interrupted with Ctrl-C? All in all, it seems that the documentation does not correspond to actual implementation, at least for the particular BIOS version your system sports.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I should try to run it on a different machine ?

Comment: If possible, yes. Another thing to consider it to study the actual implementation of INT 21h on your system. In real mode, you have access to all the memory, so you can read the IVT, find the entrypoint of 21h, dump the code section, and study it. If it shows that sub-functions 7 and 8 lead to the same code block, then you have your answer — they are identical.

Comment: Are you running this on actual HW with FreeDos/MS-Dos (even if it's virtual HW in Qemu), or in dosbox/dosemu? Emulator may have implementation of DOS services done on the host side (code of emulator itself, *not* running on the emulated 80x86 CPU), and they may reuse implementation for similar services without being worried about subtle inaccuracies like Ctrl+C handling. (just now I did notice the date of OP ... hmm... :D .. question necromancy...)

Comment: dosbox-x does not check CTRL+C when using 0x07, but it checks it when using 0x08.
And according to HelpPC, techhelpmanual, and http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm that's the only difference between 0x07 and 0x08.
I strongly recommend you testing your code on both dosbox and dosbox-x, because dosbox-x fixes a lot of dosbox's bugs.